# mail is not going when i clicked in forgot password with magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am working in Magento v1.8.0.1.The problem is when i clicked in forgot password link, the mail is not going. I checked `Admin > System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Mail Sending Settings and change Disable Email Communications to No`

Then also the problem is same.
The code for account reset password in `app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout/customer.xml`

```
<customer_account_resetpassword translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
                <title>Reset a Password</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
                <title>Reset a Password</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="customer/account_resetpassword" name="resetPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_resetpassword>
```

if anyone know this,please help me out.
Now I understood though site is hosted in linux server so In `System-> configuration -> Advanced -> system -> mail sending settings` there will be some other value for localhost and port because it is only for windows, now anyone can tell me what will be the value of localhost and port for linux server
Thanks!

Comment: anyone have any idea then please tell me its urgent

Comment: plzzzz if anyone have any idea then plz help me bcoz mail is not going for forgot password,order,registration etc